# Azure DevOps Pipeline rootdirectory

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, root

I'm trying to get the dist file from my project in Azure DevOps with the rootdirectory. But no matter what I do, I continue to get this error:

> ##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat >'D:\a\1\s\dist'

> ##[error]Ftp Upload failed

> ##[warning]Could not find any files to upload

I've tried multiple things in order to solve it, but it doesn't seem to work. Examples of what I tried are putting those lines in the rootdirectory:

> '.'

> $(Pipeline.Workspace)

> $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/rootFolderName

I found those lines in a StackOverflow post, but it keeps sending the wrong files into my FTP server.

Answer (score 4):

To access the files in your repository, you should use the following:

```
$distFilePath = "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$folderName/$distFileName"
```